# Flex items exceed width of parent in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I have a `ul > li > a > img` parenthesis and am using **flexbox** to align all list items on to a single row whilst the images are maintaining their aspect ratio's.

What it looks like in **Chrome** *45*, **Firefox** *40*, **Safari** *8*, **Opera** *28* & **Edge**

[image]

What it looks like in **IE 10/11**
[image]

So my problem is that i'm trying to achieve in *IE* the same behaviour as i have in *Chrome and Firefox*.

My **SASS/SCSS**

```scss
ul.images {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: auto; // Required for Firefox
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid yellow;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;

  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  li {
    border: 2px solid green;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0; // Required by Firefox
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;

    img {
      float: left; // Removes phantom margin
      width: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      max-height: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a **[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/BYNNgp)** for anyone wanting a more detailed look.

Comment: It also exceeds in Firefox 40.0.3

Comment: I'm almost certain it's because Firefox and IE adhere to the W3C spec perfectly and it's actually an error at my end. However i don't fully interpret / understand the spec well enough to write the correct code.

Comment: for `ul` and `container` add `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @lolka_bolka this wouldn't achieve anything other than hiding the overflowed content.

Comment: I have fixed Firefox using min-width: 0; This was because Firefox changed its default min value to default.

Comment: @Matt min-width: 0 on what?

Comment: I'm still stuck on this in case there's any nice solutions out there.. Will post here if I find one I guess.

Comment: Sorry Charlie there isn't yet, you need to use a js solution

Answer (score 4):

Change the `<img>` width from auto to 100%

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

It seems that's Chrome who doesn't respect standard

Comment: Mh, Chrome doesn't respect the ratio this way but IE/FF do

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question though. But thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the way you want the problem to be solved, but I've added in

```
li{
  height: 100%
}
```

and few other things and it seems to be working here:

EDIT: updated the demo, the ratio seems to be fine now for Chrome and IE

http://jsfiddle.net/uf30wuwz/3/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i'm trying to preserve the aspect ratio as in the Chrome result :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and found this fix, just add this to your style sheet:

```
*{
min-height: 0;
min-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution: add 'overflow: **hidden**' to class '**.images**'

At commenters:

True, guys, missed that one, sorry. @mathijs, technically true, but CSS is full of hacks (needs to be). Consider the clearfix hack, for example, which seems to be commongood nowadays.

But in this case, where the main container has a max width of 500px, hiding the overflow seems the best choice when the sum of the scaled image widths does not fit in the image container. It's a bit of an either/or situation.

BTW: Chrome is less close to W3C specs than FF (DE 42+), I'd opt to start using FF for your initial testing and then test it in Ch to detect quirks. I bet Ch hides the overflow internally.

@Matt, I'd stick to the 'overflow: hidden' solution, in a larger project it's rather trivial and does the job.

I was wondering, do you really need **ul/li** ?? With a bit of redesiging the code it gets less complicated and condensed, have a look:

@Matt again: Apparently Ch cuts excessive element data when their container has a fixed width, like yours, while FF and IE expect you to tell them what to do with it (W3C).
I have changed class 'rew-images' from 'overflow:hidden' to 'overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden', now you can see why you need to do something with overflow.

The source of your problem lies in the fact that you want the images nicely aligned **AND** have a proper scaling ratio (as I would too). But the sum of the resulting image widths is larger than 500px (minus margins etc.), so class 'images' gets overflowed. You simply can't put 600px in a container of 500px AND maintain the aspect ratio. You will have to do some cutting or remove the width constraint of the main container (remove width: 500px ). As I said before: either/or...

```css
.rew-container {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px
}
.rew-images {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden
}
.rew-images img {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100px
}
.rew-images a {
  flex: 1 1;
  border: 2px solid green;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rew-container">
  <div class="rew-images">
    <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-q8j1nkqwHnE/Tsbs1isbCTI/AAAAAAAAAG4/mcWdJwJ5uvE/s1600/armin_van_buuren_%25282%2529_798.jpg" title="armin_van_buuren_%282%29_798.jpg">
      <img src="https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=JN.d1jQ4iuFK0%2b4AkstmpzD1A&amp;pid=15.1" alt="armin_van_buuren_%282%29_798.jpg" height="168" width="300">
    </a>
    <a href="http://thegun2oo5.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/1140_armin_van_buuren.jpg" title="Armin van Buuren – the best Dj’ in the world :X:X:X">
      <img src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=JN.RTJ8eeB%2bIMptSFcLhGpXQw&amp;pid=15.1" alt="" height="480" width="444">
    </a>
    <a href="http://thexipiron.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/armin-van-buuren.jpg" title="armin van buuren">
      <img src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=JN.VkPvTXw%2fPEOMmOcl9smvoQ&amp;pid=15.1" alt="armin van buuren" height="360" width="480">
    </a>
    <a href="http://fondosdedj.com/wp-content/uploads/images/74/armin-van-buuren.jpg" title="Nos encanta la música de Armin van Buuren, y lo queremos demostrar ...">
      <img src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=JN.SvQClhGAAGcPYl1U2SZQsA&amp;pid=15.1" alt="Nos encanta la música de Armin van Buuren, y lo queremos demostrar ..." height="315" width="480">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't consider this as a `solution`. This is just preventing it from blocking other elements.

Comment: Exactly what @MatthijsvanHest said. Also this has previously been suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, it doesnt actually need to be ul li so i'm perfectly happy changing the code but very uncomfortable using the overflow hidden. I'll have a play when im home from the office and update!

Comment: There's no clear advantage to not using a list in this case, so i'm going to keep working on finding a better solution!